# Connection refused in Laravel Mysql project, while doing artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection 
refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where 
table_schema = QualityBooks and table_name = migrations)

at     /Users/lakhanpals/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/lv-bookstoreAS/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a 
query, we'll format the error
661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
663|         catch (Exception $e) {
> 664|             throw new QueryException(
665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666|             );
667|         }
668| 

 Exception trace:

 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
  /Users/lakhanpals/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/lv- bookstoreAS/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=QualityBooks", "root", "", [])
  /Users/lakhanpals/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/lv-bookstoreAS/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

I have gone through so many posts, but not sure why my "php artisan migrate" is not working and I am getting this error. I have gone through so many posts on stack but this is not working, have restarted my mac as well. no luck

database config file

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Gj0+OwDiMt7ocVTD4f8UJaj77oWw7oGz2HGh8LFBLs0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=QualityBooks
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

phpmyadmin database privilleges.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrpAQ.png)

Comment: Could you please provide database config connection

Comment: Please use the coding highlight boxes to separate out from your written texts. It would be easier for the reviewers and potential answerers to read.

Comment: Check your .env file is ok. Then restart the xampp or artisan server once again after changing .env file

Comment: Make sure that your database user has access to all tables on @127.0.0.1. You can try changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost in your .env.

Comment: I have gone through so many stack questions and answers and tried all methods, even restarted my mac, still not working, even tried clearing cache and config